# Perfectly positioned tooltips with position: fixed

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, tooltip

I'm trying to create some very basic tooltips but I'm having trouble calculating the exact position these should go in with some JavaScript. The reason for wanting a fixed position is to make sure these work whenever there is overflow hidden and such.

This is my code so far:

```
var overflowTooltip = function (elem) {

    let legendRow = elem.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    let tooltip = elem.currentTarget.children[2];
    let topPosition;
    let leftPosition;

    if ((elem.currentTarget.offsetWidth < elem.currentTarget.scrollWidth) && tooltip !== undefined) {

        tooltip.classList.add('total-opacity');

        $timeout(function () {
            if (tooltip.offsetHeight > 35) {
                topPosition = (legendRow.top - tooltip.offsetHeight / 4) - 65;
            } else {
                topPosition = legendRow.top - 65;
            }

            leftPosition = (legendRow.left + elem.currentTarget.offsetWidth) / 2;

            tooltip.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
            tooltip.style.top = topPosition + 'px';

            $timeout(function () {
                tooltip.classList.remove('total-opacity');
            }, 400)

        }, 100);
    } else {
        elem.currentTarget.children[2].style.left = '-9999px';
    }

}
```

And some SASS:

```
    .custom-tooltip {
        font-family: $brand-font-condensed;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: left;
        overflow: visible !important;
        background-color: rgba($dark-gray, 0.95);
        color: #fff;
        height: auto;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        z-index: 9000;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(#000, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(#000, 0.12);
        @include transition (.2s ease-in);
        left: -9999px;
        &:hover {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            @include transition (.2s ease-out);
            -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
            transition-delay: .3s;
        }
    }
```

The above works but it's not perfect. if I wanna change around the position for it to appear on the left, right, bottom. I'd have to so some refactoring. If the tooltip's height is bigger or smaller, the position changes, If I scroll up or down, the tooltip stays stuck on screen for a few seconds. etc. Lots of these little details which are pretty annoying.

Not interested in using a plugin at the moment nor jQuery. Thanks for any suggestion or feedback :)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey, I posted my problem, code, and even a screenshot.. don't know what else anyone would need. Regardless I solved my problem, thanks.